# Allowing the user to name the file name but keep it in a predetermined location - OSX

Tags: c++, macos, fstream

Hey I'm trying to use the fstream library to create a new text file to input whatever into. Im trying to allow the user to name the file name using a string. But as I'm currently coding on OSX I'm trying to keep the file within a folder that I have already created

This is the portion of the code.

```
cout << "What date is it today? e.g "11.05.1990"" << endl;
cin >> filename;

filename += ".txt";

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(filename.c_str());
```

But what I want to do is put the file into a folder under the directory '/Users/Matt/Desktop/Diary'. How would I be able to that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the file to be located in '/your/path/here' you have to append it to your filename like this.

```
string path = "/Users/Matt/Desktop/Diary/";
filename = (path + filename + ".txt");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know why that didn't click in my head